# Adding components to path - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a url say : `www.gmail.com/index.php`. I also have three different strings say `aa`, `bb` and `cc`. I want to append the three separate strings to the url in order to get a combined url in Objective C i.e I want `www.gmail.com/index.php/aa/bb/cc` .
Can someone help me out ?? I am new to objective C. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `http://www.gmail.com/index.php`?   `www.gmail.com/index.php` isn't a URL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are trying to use a URL for later use in retrieving data, etc., you're going to want an `NSURL` object when you're done.   You can certainly create a URL by appending @"/%@" with the next element, but you should look at doing the following:

```
NSURL *originalURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.gmail.com/"];
NSURL *aaNextURL = [originalURL URLByAppendingPathComponent: @"aa"];
NSURL *bbNextURL = [aaNextURL URLByAppendingPathComponent: @"bb"];
NSURL *ccNextURL = [bbNextURL URLByAppendingPathComponent: @"cc"];
```

This is a bit long-winded if you are adding static path elements, but if you are adding computed information it solves the problem of making sure there are appropriate slashes and allows you to use the URL construct directly.

Comment: Last line should probably read: `NSURL *ccNextURL = [bbNextURL URLByAppendingPathComponent: @"cc"];`

Answer (score 9):

Use `stringByAppendingPathComponent`