# Append variables to string in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, directory, nsstring, concatenation

I am trying to build a path using variables like this:

```
NSString *user =  NSUserName();
NNString *plugin = @"plugin@";

 NSString *docPath = @"/Users %/@", [user stringByAppendingString: @", /Movies/Motion Templates.localized/Titles.localized/@" [plugin stringByAppendingString:]"];

NSLog(@"Path: %@", docPath);
```

I am new to Objective-C and I feel like there has to be an easier way to append variables to a string.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896214/adding-components-to-path-objective-c for building paths.